# Pass Complex parameters by POST in alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode

```
let newTodo  =  [
    "currentPageNo" :  (page.description) ,
    "type": "basic_search",
    "searchParams": [
                        "remember_search" : checkk ,
                        "u_seeking": (bsMatch_looking) ,
                        "age_from" :  (bsMatch_agefrom) ,
                        "age_to": (bsMatch_ageto),
                        "u_looking_for_value" :(bsMatch_lookingfoevalue),
                        "u_country": (bsMatch_country) ,
                        "u_state" :  (bsMatch_ustate) ,
                        "u_city": (bsMatch_city) ,
                        "u_postalcode" :  (bsMatch_postelcode) ,
                        "distance": (bsMatch_distance) ,
                     ]                
                ] as [String : AnyObject]
```

response is below

```
["type": basic_search , "currentPageNo": 1 ,"searchParams": {
"age_from" = 18;
"age_to" = 44;
distance = 0;
"remember_search" = On;
"u_city" = "";
"u_country" = 1;
"u_looking_for_value" = 0;
"u_postalcode" = "";
"u_seeking" = Female;
"u_state" = California;
}]
```

But I want this type of response how can I do this only brasses makes the problem for me please provide me the solution

```
[{ "currentPageNo": 1, "type": basic_search ,"searchParams": {
"age_from" = 20;
"age_to" = 35;
distance = 100;
"remember_search" = On;
"u_city" = London;
"u_country" = 222;
"u_looking_for_value" = "0";
"u_postalcode" = "";
"u_seeking" = Male;
"u_state" = England;
}}]
```

I want to convert the first code into the second type

Comment: only {} makes a problem for me how {} are added in parameters ??

Comment: Do you want to send your parameter into the Order format?

Comment: yes sir but without {} its not work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can order them by having keys with type Int.

```
var myDictionary: [Int: [String: String]]?
```

Comment: sir plz provide me how can I added to newTodo to make last code response

Comment: Add currentPageNo in the first position, type in second and so on you can try it.

Comment: sir main thing is {} which is before the current page and  in second how in first .

Comment: Create a chat room. I will explain there.

Comment: how to add json object in this parameters